# More effective / clean way to aggregate data

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot-table

python 3.7.10
pandas 1.1.5

Imagine we have Dataframe with two columns containing categories and third column with numbers.
Task is to group by first category and then subgroup by second category and calculate totals and shares.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'fruit': ['orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana'],
    'origin': ['USA', 'Canada', 'USA', 'Canada', 'USA', 'Canada'],
    'weight': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
})
df
```

|  | fruit | origin | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | orange | USA | 1 |
| 1 | orange | Canada | 2 |
| 2 | orange | USA | 3 |
| 3 | banana | Canada | 4 |
| 4 | banana | USA | 5 |
| 5 | banana | Canada | 6 |

```
(df
 .groupby('fruit')
 .apply(lambda x: (x
                   .groupby('origin')
                   .agg({'weight': sum})
                   .assign(share=lambda x: x.weight / x.weight.sum()))
 )
)
```

| fruit | origin | weight | share |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| banana | Canada | 10 | 0.666667 |
|  | USA | 5 | 0.333333 |
| orange | Canada | 2 | 0.333333 |
|  | USA | 4 | 0.666667 |

Is there a more pythonic / pandish / cleaner way to achieve the same result.
For example, I can't rename **weight** on the fly in case it's not sum but rather count and I want column name to reflect this.

In R it looks to me much cleaner.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
  fruit = c('orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana'),
  origin = c('USA', 'Canada', 'USA', 'Canada', 'USA', 'Canada'),
  weight = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
)

df %>%
  group_by(fruit, origin) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(weight)) %>%
  mutate(share = total / sum(total))
```

I believe there is some cleaner way to do it in python.

Comment: is pandas.pivot_table a way for this ? see it -> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

Comment: @WillianVieira Thought about this. Wasn't able to come with the exact solution. Can you provide one?

Answer (score 4):

You can have two separate `groupby` statements to make it cleaner:

```
In [101]: x = df.groupby(['fruit', 'origin']).sum().reset_index()
In [104]: x['share'] = x.groupby('fruit')['weight'].apply(lambda i: i/i.sum())

In [105]: x
Out[105]: 
    fruit  origin  weight     share
0  banana  Canada      10  0.666667
1  banana     USA       5  0.333333
2  orange  Canada       2  0.333333
3  orange     USA       4  0.666667
```

**OR**, as per @Manakin's comment, avoiding apply:

```
In [101]: x = df.groupby(['fruit', 'origin']).sum().reset_index()
In [109]: x['share'] = x['weight'].div(x.groupby('fruit')['weight'].transform('sum'))

In [110]: x
Out[110]: 
    fruit  origin  weight     share
0  banana  Canada      10  0.666667
1  banana     USA       5  0.333333
2  orange  Canada       2  0.333333
3  orange     USA       4  0.666667
```

Answer (score 4):

A direct translation from your `r` code would need another `groupby`:

```
>>> ( df.groupby(['fruit', 'origin'])
        .sum().assign(
            share=lambda x: x.groupby('fruit').transform(lambda x: x / x.sum())
         )
     )
               weight     share
fruit  origin                  
banana Canada      10  0.666667
       USA          5  0.333333
orange Canada       2  0.333333
       USA          4  0.666667
```

Or,

```
>>> ( df.groupby(['fruit', 'origin'])
        .sum().assign(share=lambda x: x / x.groupby('fruit').transform(sum))
    )
 
               weight     share
fruit  origin                  
banana Canada      10  0.666667
       USA          5  0.333333
orange Canada       2  0.333333
       USA          4  0.666667
```

Or, probably the most readable:

```
>>> ( df.groupby(['fruit', 'origin']).sum()
        .assign(share=lambda x: x.div(df.groupby('fruit').sum()))
    )

               weight     share
fruit  origin                  
banana Canada      10  0.666667
       USA          5  0.333333
orange Canada       2  0.333333
       USA          4  0.666667
```

Even better with [`rdiv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rdiv.html), and finally truly one-liner :) :

```
>>> df.groupby(['fruit', 'origin']).sum().assign(share=df.groupby('fruit').sum().rdiv)
               weight     share
fruit  origin                  
banana Canada      10  0.666667
       USA          5  0.333333
orange Canada       2  0.333333
       USA          4  0.666667
```

---

Something without groupby, using `pd.melt` and `pd.crosstab`:

```
>>> df2 = df.melt(['fruit', 'origin'], var_name='stats')
>>> pd.crosstab(
        index=[df2['fruit'], df2['origin']], 
        columns=df2['stats'], 
        values=df2['value'], 
        aggfunc=sum
    ).assign(share=lambda x:x/x.sum(level=0))

stats          weight     share
fruit  origin                  
banana Canada      10  0.666667
       USA          5  0.333333
orange Canada       2  0.333333
       USA          4  0.666667
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't as "clean" as R, but it can be done in one-liner:

```
df.groupby(['fruit', 'origin'])['weight'].sum().reset_index()\
  .pipe(lambda x: x.assign(share=x['weight'] / 
                                 x.groupby('fruit')['weight'].transform('sum')))
```

Output:

```
    fruit  origin  weight     share
0  banana  Canada      10  0.666667
1  banana     USA       5  0.333333
2  orange  Canada       2  0.333333
3  orange     USA       4  0.666667
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.set_index` then use `.div` here.

```
Out = df.groupby(["fruit", "origin"]).sum()
Out = Out.assign(share=Out.div(df.set_index(["fruit", "origin"]).sum(level=0)))

               weight     share
fruit  origin                  
banana Canada      10  0.666667
       USA          5  0.333333
orange Canada       2  0.333333
       USA          4  0.666667
```

Answer (score 1):

In your R code you transformed the `sum(weight)` to rename it as `"total"` which you can do by passing in keyword arguments into a `groupby(...).agg(new_name=("column_name", aggfunc)`. You can also gain some cleanliness by writing a helper function to perform the normalization with.

```
def normalize(x):
    return x / x.sum()

out = (df.groupby(["fruit", "origin"])
         .agg(total=("weight", "sum"))
         .assign(
             share=lambda df: df.groupby("fruit").transform(normalize)
         ))

print(out)
               total     share
fruit  origin
banana Canada     10  0.666667
       USA         5  0.333333
orange Canada      2  0.333333
       USA         4  0.666667
```